# Is it possible to change the title of PKAddPassesViewController ?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios6, passbook

Every pass, when being added results in `PKAddPassesViewController` having its title automatically set according to pass type and respecting localization (Generic get "Card", event ticket gets "Event Ticket", store card gets "Store Card" and so on...); but is it possible to change the title?

I've tried setting `title` property of `PKAddPassesViewController` instance, but nothing happened, so maybe there is a attribute in `pass.json` that can control the title (I didn't find one in PassKit specs)?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way in the current framework that this title can be customised, either by the Pass Kit framework or by a pass.json key.