# modify PKAddPassesViewController title

Tags: ios, passbook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to change the title of PKAddPassesViewController ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13823607/is-it-possible-to-change-the-title-of-pkaddpassesviewcontroller)

Hello, when I add a passbook I used coupon style：

```
pass = [[PKPass alloc] initWithData:data error:&error];
PKAddPassesViewController *vc = [[PKAddPassesViewController alloc] initWithPass:pass];
[vc setDelegate:(id)self];
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

the `UIBarButtonItem` have three button：“Cancel” ，“Coupon”  “Add”
the “Coupon” is default, because I used coupon style, and I want to modify it.

I used `vc.title=@"new Title"` but this does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible to modify the title text.

See this question [Is it possible to change the title of PKAddPassesViewController ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13823607/is-it-possible-to-change-the-title-of-pkaddpassesviewcontroller)